# Search on hidden ID of enterprise wiki page only

Tags: enterprise-search, document-id, sharepoint-server

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and have set up a small knowledge base. 
I am displaying the hidden ID of the enterprise wiki page on the page using this code:

```
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="Article ID:" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></strong></b>
<SharePoint:NumberField id="XXXXX" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1" runat="server"/>
```

Now my goal is to search on this article ID and find it immediatly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a managed property for the field and call it e.g. ArticleID. Then map the crawled property for the field with the id: 1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1 to the managed property ArticleID.

Then you can search for ArticleID:123 in the searchcenter or with a search webpart and get the item.

Comment: Thanks Max ! I added the property to be a crawled property i've adjusted the advanced search page to set the ID there as one of the options so users don't have to type ArticleID